# Neural speech synthesis with children voices

Tags: language, speech-synthesis

I am programming an automatic dubbing of children's videos into multiple languages. The missing piece is a text-to-speech with lifelike children's voices.

[Amazon Polly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/voicelist.html) has children's neural voices in US English only. [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices) has more language but does not have children's voices and raising the voice's pitch by 10 semitones does not produce enjoyable results.

I am looking for a text-to-speech system with the following characteristics:

- multiple languages, like Google Cloud
- children's voices, like Amazon Polly
- lifelike speech synthesis with neural voices, like Google Cloud or Amazon Polly
- support for SSML tags like `prosody` (rate, pitch, volume) and `emphasis`

Could you recommend some systems?